# Evaluating $\sum_{t=1}^{50}\frac{t^{2}}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{10}\right)^t}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{t=1}^{50}\frac{t^{2}}{\left(1 + \frac{1}{10}\right)^t}$$

I am getting no clue on how to approach this type of problem since no simple type of sequence techniques seems to work here.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed, I was just trying to get more information from OP

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**

You are looking at the series of the form $f(x) = \sum_t t^2 x^t$. Note that if we start with a geometric series $g(x) = \sum_t x^t$ then
$$
\begin{split}
g'(x)  &= \sum_t tx^{t-1}\\
xg'(x) &= x \sum_t tx^{t-1} = \sum_t tx^t
\end{split}
$$
Can you apply this trick again to $xg'(x)$ to get $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

Set
$$
f(x)=\sum_t t^2e^{-axt}
$$
where $a=\ln 1.1$.
Then
$$
\int_x^\infty dx'\int_{x'}^\infty  f(x'')dx''=\sum_t \frac{e^{-axt}}{a^2}
$$
You can then sum the right hand side (geometric series in $t$) and differentiate it twice to get $f(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The required sum is $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 x^k,~~ x=(1+1/10)^{-1}$$

$$x+x^2+x^3+...x^n=x\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k $$
differentiating it w.r.t. x both sides
$$xf'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k x^k$$ diferentiating again we get
$$x[f'(x)+xf''(x)]=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 x^k$$
Where $f(x)=x(x^n-1)/(x-1)$ and $x=(1+1/10)^{-1}.$.